# How apply initial value of GridColumn -> GridColumnMenuFilter (Kendo React)?

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-react-ui

I need to set the initial filter value inside GridColumnMenuFilter.

The problem: initial value applies to filter under title but not apply to filter inside GridColumnMenuFilter.

[filter under the title with initial value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnRX6.png)

[filter inside GridColumnMenuFilter without initial value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK0MY.png)

Code example:

```
const initialFilter: CompositeFilterDescriptor = {
    logic: "and",
    filters: [
      {
        field: "isAdmin",
        operator: "eq",
        value: true,
      },
    ],
  };

  const GridColumnMenu = (props: GridColumnMenuProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div>
      <GridColumnMenuFilter {...props} expanded={true} hideSecondFilter />
    </div>
  );
};

 const columnProps = (
  field: string
) => {
  return {
    field: field,
    columnMenu: GridColumnMenu
  };
};

  <Grid           
        data={tableData.data}           
        filterable={true}
        filter={initialFilter}            
      >
    <GridColumn
       title={"Is Admin>"}
       {...columnProps("isAdmin")} />
    ...
 </Grid>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial filter value must be like this:

```
const initialFilter: CompositeFilterDescriptor = {
filters: [
  {
    logic: "and",
    filters: [
      {
        field: "isAdmin",
        operator: "eq",
        value: true,
      },
    ],
  },
],
logic: "and",
```

};

and then the filter will work fine inside **GridColumnMenuFilter**.